# XPath: select text after certain tag and before same next tag

Tags: xpath

I have html code like this:

```
<strong>Term:</strong>
Some text<br />
More text<br />
Some more lines of text
<strong>Term:</strong>
Some text<br />
More text<br />
Some more lines of text
<strong>Second term:</strong>
Some text<br />
More text<br />
Some more lines of text
<strong>Term:</strong>
Some text<br />
More text<br />
Some more lines of text
```

I need to get text nodes between tag  with text "Term" and before next  tag:

```
Some text
More text
Some more lines of text
Some text
More text
Some more lines of text
Some text
More text
Some more lines of text
```

Here can be used condition: previous tag  must contains text "Term", but I don't know how to create xpath selector like this.

Comment: Hi, I feel the question is not very clear.
Can you please post what is the desired output. May be then I can understand what exactly you want.

Comment: I made update the question. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You have changed your input, please update also the wanted output. Moreover add meaningful text to differentiate among chilren ndoes. By your description it's still hard to understand what you need.

Comment: I've extended my answer, even if still in doubt about your needings. See if it's ok for you.

Answer (score 6):

```
//text()[preceding::*[contains(text(),'Term:')] and following::*[contains(text(),'Term:')]]
```

It's same as what empo has suggested. However I'm looking for a node containing Term and returning all text nodes present between them.

However, this works fine only if you don't have any other set of "Term".
Let me know if that is the case, because then this Xpath will return some unwanted values also.

Since now you have updated the input.
I have simply put one more condition to the previous Xpath.

```
//text()[preceding::*[contains(text(),'Term:')] and following::*[contains(text(),'Term:')] and not(contains(., 'Term:'))]
```

@empo solution also works. But there we are taking `<strong>` into account. The xpath that I have written simply checks for word **'Term:'** and gives out all the textNodes between them.

Let me know if this works for you.

Regards.

Comment: Your solution works excelent, but returns only one match. What if I need to get all text after all tags with text "Term"?

Comment: @Stephan you should show us much more of your input document.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is still ambiguous and your input document is not well formed. Check this:

```
root/text()[preceding::strong[1][contains(text(),'Term')]]
```

Applied on:

```
<root>
<strong>Term:</strong>
Some text<br />
More text<br />
Some more lines of text
<strong>Term:</strong>
Some text2<br />
More text2<br />
Some more lines of text2
<strong>Second term:</strong>
Some text3<br />
More text3<br />
Some more lines of text3
<strong>Term:</strong>
Some text4<br />
More text4<br />
Some more lines of text4
</root>
```

produces:

```
Some text
More text
Some more lines of text

Some text2
More text2
Some more lines of text2

Some text4
More text4
Some more lines of text4
```

---

This XPath, selects all text nodes between an element containing the string `Term:` and an element containing any string:

```
//text()[preceding::*[contains(text(),'Term:')] and following::*[text()]]
```

Applied on:

```
<root>
<strong>Term:</strong>
Some text<br />
More text<br />
Some more lines of text
<strong>Second term:</strong>
Some text2<br />
More text2<br />
Some more lines of text2
</root>
```

Returns:

```
Some text
More text
Some more lines of text
```